# how to correctly return a const with a button in a TextArea ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, input, state

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

I have 2 const

```
const a = data.hi?.map((e) =>
    e?.hello?.label.toString()
);


const b = data.hi?.map((e) =>
 e?.bye?.label.toString());
```

currently, I have 2 buttons

```
<>
  <Button> A </Button>

  <Button> B </Button>
</>
```

I also have input text and state

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");

   <TextArea value={text} />
```

and so I am looking for when I click on button "A", it returns the value of my const "a" in my TextArea.

I am open to any proposal thank you very much.

thanks, Neff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple

```
<Button onclick={() => {setText(a)}>
   A
 </Button>
```